# How to create a filter for a domain in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to create a filter that works for a specific domain and redirects a user from any page they try to visit if they have gone over a quota. So far, the code does not redirect at all.

Here is what I have so far in `filters.php`:

```
Route::filter('domain', function () {
    if (stripos(Request::root(), Config::get('domains.main')) !== false) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            $max_quota = Plan::where('id', $user->plan_id)->where('is_active', true)->pluck('max_quota');

            $quota_used = Quota::where('user_id', $user->id)->count();

            if (empty($max_quota)) {
                return Redirect::to('account/error/inactive');
            } elseif ($quota_used >= $max_quota) {
                return Redirect::to('account/error/over_quota');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Even if I put this in `routes.php` under:

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('domains.main')], function () {

    Route::filter('*', function () { /* Same code here... */ });

}
```

It will then get into the filter function, successfully check the criteria, but the redirect still doesn't happen.

I think I am missing more than one key point here. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, I needed to change:

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('domains.main')], function () {
```

To:

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('domains.main'), 'before' => 'domain'], function () {
```

I also needed to add redirect loop protection to this line:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
```

So that it becomes:

```
if (Auth::check() && !strpos(Request::fullUrl(), 'account/error')) {
```